# Dagger 2 Good practices to build components in Application class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I know probably there is no clear answer for this question.

But I would like to know Your opinions and maybe new ideas.

I'm wondering which of the following options is the best/right/correct way to build the app-level Dagger Component in Application class.

---

**Example 1:**

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private NetComponent mNetComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this)) 
                .netModule(new NetModule("https://api.github.com"))
                .build();
    }

    public NetComponent getNetComponent() {
        return mNetComponent;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
((MyApp) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
```

---

**Example 2:**

```
 class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyComponent component;

    @Override
    void onCreate() {
        component = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(getApplicationContext()))
                .build();
    }

    public static MyComponent getMyComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
MyApplication.getMyComponent().inject(this)
```

---

**Example 3:**

```
class CustomApplication: Application() {
    lateinit var component: SingletonComponent
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        INSTANCE = this
        component = DaggerSingletonComponent.builder()
                       .contextModule(ContextModule(this))
                       .build()
    }

    companion object {
       private var INSTANCE: CustomApplication? = null

       @JvmStatic
       fun get(): CustomApplication = INSTANCE!!

    }
}
```

Then:

```
class Injector private constructor() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun get() : SingletonComponent = CustomApplication.get().component
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Injector.get().catRepository()
```

---

**Example 4:**

```
 class App : Application() {

    var repositoryComponent: RepositoryComponent? = null
    var appComponent: AppComponent? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
        repositoryComponent = DaggerRepositoryComponent.builder().build()
    }

    companion object {

        private var instance: App? = null

        fun get(): App {
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 App.get().repositoryComponent!!.inject(this)
```

What do you think about this? Is there any better / cleaner way to do this? Maybe provided examples are fine? Or maybe just one of them?

**I will be grateful for any good examples / tips / advices.**

**Thanks!**

Comment: Looking at `NetComponent` makes me cry, and I'm super-biased because `Option #3` and the `Injector.get()` originates from my article, so I won't post any answers on this one.

Comment: Yes Option #3 it's from Your article and it inspired me. I just wanted to confront it with other options and show other peoples because its looks quite good :)

Comment: If we keep up the silence I'll answer it though

Answer (score 3):

Okay, no one answered in 5 days so it's my turn, despite my bias :p

- Option #1

`((MyApp) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);`

It's an "ok" version of doing things, except for two things.

First, the name. `NetComponent` isn't really for networking, it's the app-global singleton component, so it should be either called `SingletonComponent` or `AppComponent`. But naming it `NetComponent` is disingenuous, it's typically responsible for *everything else* too.

Second problem is that you need a reference to `Context` to access your dependency graph, making `Context` actually be a *dependency* rather than it being provided to you.

- Option #2

`MyApplication.getMyComponent().inject(this)`

This is a perfectly fine way of doing things, but you need to know that to reach your object graph, you need to access the static method of `MyApplication`.

- Option #3

`Injector.get().inject(this)`

Internally, this solution actually just calls over to get the app component, `public static AppComponent get() { return MyApplication.getInstance().getComponent(); }`

The benefit is that `getComponent()` is exposed via an instance method of Application, so it could be theoretically swapped out.

Also, invoking a method on something called `Injector.get()` is more obviously an "injector" than, well, an application class.

As for whether you use `.catRepository()` or `.inject(this)`, it's up to you; but I personally prefer calling the provision methods to get the deps in Activity/Fragment, because listing the member-injection targets adds a lot of clutter to the component over time.

4.)

`App.get().repositoryComponent!!.inject(this)`

You can ditch the `!!` if `repositoryComponent` is a `lateinit var`.

Having two components for the same scope (and therefore two different object graphs) will only cause trouble, out of all of the options, this is the worst.

---

In my opinion, the 3rd option is the best. Technically it's the same as option #2 with an additional "indirection" through the instance method of Application that actually returns the component.

Comment: is option 3 still considered as the best approach ?

Comment: It works well if your app is single-module. But you only need that accessor if you are in a class that cannot be `@Inject`ed (activity, fragment, other android components)